# Markdwn to PDF compilation wih pandoc through vim with a command

Tags: pdf, vim, markdown, pandoc

I use pandoc markdown as my main tool for generating document using **vim**. When I need to compile the document I usually type

```
:!pandoc Something.rmd --pdf-engine=xelatex -o Something.pdf
```

But, when I compile document using LaTeX I've mapped Ctrl+C to autocompile the PDF, I use those two lines of code "stolen" from [Luke Smith](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz):

`autocmd FileType tex inoremap <C-C> <Esc>:!xelatex<space><c-r>%<Enter>a
autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <C-C> :!xelatex<space><c-r>%<Enter>`

Since I'm not an expert in vim programming and I do not understand very well how the .vimrc works (I'm learning slowly), I was wondering if there is a method to bind some key (eg. Ctrl+C) to the automatic compilation of a PDF file from a markdown document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want the Markdown equivalent of the LaTeX mappings, right?!

Let's first tidy up the original ones; unfortunately, many people just copy-and-paste stuff seen somewhere on the Internet without fully understanding it. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove to be a very powerful and efficient editor.

```
autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <C-C> :!xelatex<space><c-r>%<Enter>
autocmd FileType tex inoremap <C-C> <Esc>:!xelatex<space><c-r>%<Enter>a
```

- There's no need for the `<space>` special notation.
- The mapping will be defined *globally*, but we only want this for the LaTeX buffers. This is important once you've defined your Markdown variant, should you ever edit both in the same Vim session. `<buffer>` will make this a local mapping.
- The [`c_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R) inserts the special `%` register, which stands for the current file. But this is not necessary, in the `:!` command, we can directly refer to it via `%`. Cp. [`:help cmdline-special`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special)
- For the insert mode mapping [`i_CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) can be used instead of `<Esc>...a`.

```
autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <buffer> <C-C> :!xelatex %<Enter>
```

Now that we have that, we can define the variant for Markdown. It's [`filetype`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#filetype) (found out via `:setl filetype?`) is `markdown`.

```
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <buffer> <C-C> !pandoc % --pdf-engine=xelatex -o %:r.pdf
```

That `%:r` is another special notation that strips off the last extension from the current filename, so that we can append the `.pdf` instead.

I'll leave the insert mode variant to you, for practice :-)

#### Final words

I would recommend putting any settings, mappings, and filetype-specific autocmds into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_whatever.vim` (or `{filetype}/whatever.vim`; cp. `:help ftplugin-name`) instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though. Settings that *override* stuff in default filetype plugins should go into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` instead.

Comment: Actually I do not why today the markdown version started to not work. Have you any idea of the cause?

Comment: No, but as a first step I would check whether the problem is inside Vim or outside, e.g. by using `:! echo pandoc... `

Comment: Actually the latex version of your snippet works but the markdown not, and doing `:!echo pandoc % -o %:r.pdf` actually prints `pandoc myfile.md -o myfile.pdf`.

Comment: That looks fine, so there might be a problem with pandoc. You could try calling it outside of Vim.

Comment: Already done it, it works, I do not really know how to deal with it